# Onestep checkout shipping price not displayed

Tags: shipping, onestepcheckout

[image]I have an issue in One Step Checkout with Total and subtotal prices including shipping not being displayed after shipping method selection. I get only product price:

[image: Screenshot of order review]

Do you have any ideas? This is the part I'm missing (tooked from other magento e-shop):

[image]

Comment: Can u explain in detail? The shipping price will display in total area under cart table.

Comment: It doesn't display total price in order review in checkout page, right before PLACE ORDER button.

Comment: @Liguru I think this is cart page so you are asking for estimate shipping block right?

Comment: @Liguru , send full page screenshot with highlight.